# How to create a "following" table?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I am designing a simple twitter site ( for study ) but with a little bit different: the users can follow other users, keywords and lists. I want to know how to create a following table to put information about following.

Is this approach ( below ) correct ?

Following Table:

```
id ( id of the following table )
type ( type can be 1 ( user ), 2 ( keyword ) or 3 ( list ) )
idtype ( id of the type table )
user ( user's id )
```

However there isn't a keyword table. So I don't know.

What is the best approach ?

Comment: Why isn't there a keyword table?

Comment: because the keywords are in the tweet.

Answer (score 1):

It's incorrect because you can't create a foreign key from `idtype` to the parent table, because "parent table" changes depending on `type`. BTW, if user can follow multiple keywords, then you won't escape having a separate table for that (unless you want to [break the 1NF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form#Atomicity) by "packing" several values into the same field, which is a really bad idea).

There are couple of ways to resolve this, probably the simplest one is to use separate `id` fields for each of the possible parent tables, and then constrain them so only one of them can be non-NULL.

**However**, since [InnoDB tables are clustered](http://www.ovaistariq.net/521/understanding-innodb-clustered-indexes/) and secondary indexes in clustered tables are expensive, I'd rather go with something like this (tweets table not shown):

[image]

This will enable you to very efficiently answer the query: "which users follow the given user (or keyword or list)". If you need to answer: "which users (or keywords or lists) the given user follows", reverse the order of fields in the PKs shown above. If you need both, then you'd need indexes in both directions (and pay the clustering price).